# How does form checkboxes and radio buttons work with React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a form in one of my React components. Input and Textarea works fine, but I can't even get the checkbox or radio button to show up. Neither render, but the labels for them do. I followed the tutorial on [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org), but with no luck.

Am I missing something?

**Here's what I have:**

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             isChecked: true
        };

        this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleCheckboxChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label>
                        <input name="isChecked" 
                               type="checkbox" 
                               checked={this.state.isChecked} 
                               onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}/>
                    ONE</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               name="isChecked" 
                               checked={this.state.isChecked} 
                               onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} />
                    TWO</label>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @DragonBorn I don't get any errors. The checkbox itself just doesn't show up, but the label shows up.

Answer (score 1):

*(Apologies, as I do not have enough reputation to post a comment)*

Your question is not clear, but I assume the issue you are facing is that you component is not rendering on screen.

There seems to be no problem with your code and the check boxes are showing up correctly.
Check out a JSFiddle I tried out.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://reactjs.org/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

**Javascript 1.7**

```
class Example extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         isChecked: true
    };

    this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
}

handleCheckboxChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <input name="isChecked" 
                           type="checkbox" 
                           checked={this.state.isChecked} 
                           onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}/>
                ONE</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                           name="isChecked" 
                           checked={this.state.isChecked} 
                           onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} />
                TWO</label>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
}



  class HelloWidget extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div className="widget">
             <Example/>
           </div>;
    }
  }

  React.render(<HelloWidget />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

**JSFiddle link to check the output**

http://jsfiddle.net/sam_fisher_nexus/jwm6k66c/3982/

Comment: That's really weird! Mine still doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. And by "not working", I mean.. the checkbox itself doesn't show up, but the label name (e.g., ONE, TWO) does.

Would it have something to do with how many parent/children components there are?

Comment: Never mind, I got it! This code does work. It was just that [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) had the checkbox styling to be `position: fixed;` and `opacity: 0`. Thank you for confirming that the code does work though!